# MongoEngine delete nested embedded document?

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a collection with en embedded document that has a list of embedded documents and need to be able to delete alert_list index [x] but have not been able to craft a pull command that works. Here my model structure:

```
class Alert(medb.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = medb.StringField(default = 'new alert')

class Sensor(medb.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = medb.StringField(default='')
    alert_list = medb.ListField(medb.EmbeddedDocumentField(Alert), default=Alert)

class SiteConfig(medb.Document):
    name = medb.StringField(default = 'name')
    sensordict = medb.MapField(medb.EmbeddedDocumentField(Sensor))


#delete alert_item #2 for sensordict['99']
SiteConfig.objects(id=siteid).update_one(pull__  ????? what goes here???
```

I can do it in pymongo like this ( and it works just fine):

```
#load site into pymongo
pysite = pydb.db.SiteConfig.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(siteid)})
#delete the alert
del pysite['sensordict'][sensorid]['alert_list'][alertindex]
#save modified Site back to db
pydb.db.SiteConfig.replace_one({'_id': ObjectId(siteid)}, pysite, upsert=True)
```

But would prefer to use MongoEngine if possible. - any suggestions?
Thanks
Bill

Comment: I'm having the same problem right now. Is there a native mongoengine solution for this? In any case, the delete functionality of mongoengine seems to be pretty broken when it comes to such use cases.